# How to store functions in Dictionary with uint as key (C#)

Tags: c#, function, dictionary

Can someone provide me an example of how maybe I store different functions in a dictionary with int as a key and function as value. So then I could easly call function as following:

```
functionsDictionary[123](string);
```

Note all functions in dictionary will take only one input which is string. And will have no return.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813261/how-to-store-delegates-in-a-list

Comment: Kinda is duplicate, kinda not. But I forgot to mention that I would like to add functions to dictionary using dictionary.add method. List != Dictionary :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you're after

```
Dictionary<int, Action<string>>
```

or possibly (based on your title)

```
Dictionary<uint, Action<string>>
```

Sample:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, Action<string>>
        {
            { 5, x => Console.WriteLine("Action for 5: {0}", x) },
            { 13, x => Console.WriteLine("Unlucky for some: {0}", x) }
        };

        dictionary[5]("Woot");
        dictionary[13]("Not really");

        // You can add later easily too
        dictionary.Add(10, x => Console.WriteLine("Ten {0}", x));
        dictionary[15] = x => Console.WriteLine("Fifteen {0}", x);

        // Method group conversions work too
        dictionary.Add(0, MethodTakingString);
    }

    static void MethodTakingString(string x)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: How about adding functions with dictionary.Add() ?

Comment: @user621033: Edited my answer to give an example of that.

Comment: What about adding function name that already exist like here http://pastebin.com/TYfs2u1x

Comment: @user621033: Your Login method doesn't take a string, so you can't add it like that. However, I've edited my answer to give an example of a method group conversion.

Comment: That's what I missed. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Dictionary<int, Action<string>> _functions = new Dictionary<int, Action<string>>();
_functions[123]("hello");
```