# Array containing Methods

Tags: c#, arrays, methods

I was wondering if you can create an Array or a List<> that contains methods. I don't want to use a switch or lots of if statements.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to store delegates in a List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813261/how-to-store-delegates-in-a-list)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There you go

```
List<Action> list = new List<Action>();
list.Add( () => ClassA.MethodX(paramM) );
list.Add( () => ClassB.MethodY(paramN, ...) );

foreach (Action a in list) {
    a.Invoke();
}
```

Comment: Why is the `Invoke()` here? Can't you just do `a()`?

Comment: @Vilx- Yes you can use `a()`. And you don't need a heavy `List<T>` for this. You can do `new Action[] { ()=> MyMethod(), ()=> MyMethod2() };`

Comment: explain what you mean by ListT

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it is possible to have such an array or list. Depending on the number of input or output parameters, you'd use something like

```
List<Func<T1, T2, TReturn>>
```

An instance of type `Func<T1, T2, TReturn>` is a method like

```
TReturn MyFunction(T1 input1, T2 input2)
```

[Take a look at the MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to replace a switch then a Dictionary might be more useful than a List

```
var methods = new Dictionary<string, Action>()
              {
                  {"method1", () => method1() },
                  {"method2", () => method2() }
              };

methods["method2"]();
```

I consider this and switch statements a code smell and they can often be [replaced by polymorphism](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism).

Comment: That depends where you want to use this. What if you try to implement the command pattern? It's perfectly fine in such case. (also it's better to use a list)

Comment: Why is it better to use a list?

Comment: Since with command pattern you usually want to loop through the callbacks

Comment: Thanks for saying it's a smell. Just because you can do something, doesn't mean that you should.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to try this if u don't want to use Lists

```
public    Action[] methods;

private void methodsInArray()
{

    methods= new Action[2];
    methods[0] = test ;
    methods[1] = test1;
}

private void test()
{
    //your code
}

private void test1()
{
    //your code
}
```

Answer (score -1):

object[] arrProc = new object[2];

arrProc[0] = (string)Fx1();

arrProc[1] = (string)Fx2();

string aa = (string)arrProc[0];

Comment: This doesn't answer the question asked. Your code will put the _results_ of the method calls into an array, while the OP wanted to have _methods_ themselves there.