# Array Containing Methods/Functions for Argument Passing

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, function-pointers, method-reference

I have a method that selects between the arguments of an array and returns a specific one. For instance, here is that method:

```
private <T> T selectOnType(T[] selection, T defaultOp){
    switch(this.type){
        case Resources.TEXT:
            return selection[Resources.TEXT];
        case Resources.LISTEN:
            return selection[Resources.LISTEN];
        default:
            return defaultOp;
    }
}
```

How can I construct an array full of method references (i.e. function pointers) in order to be able to pass that array into this method above?

I tried doing such things as:

```
java.util.function.Function<Void, Void>[] array = {ClassA::method1, ClassA::method2};
```

*(where method1 and method1 take no arguments and return void)*

But that throws a compiler error saying:

> incompatible types: invalid method reference but expected no arguments.
>      found: java.lang.Void
>      reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

I have been playing around with lambdas such as:

```
() -> ClassA.method1()
```

But I haven't been able to get it to work. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong and know a solution to this problem?

EDIT:
I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712137/array-containing-methods) on *Stack Overflow*, but this is for C# and I haven't figured out how to mimic it in Java.

**Example:**
Let's say I have a `Word` class:

```
public class Word{
    private final String text;
    private int listenCorrect = 0, textCorrect = 0;
    public Word(final String test){
        this.text = text;
    }
    public void incListenCorrect(){
        listenCorrect++;
    }
    public void incTextCorrect(){
        textCorrect--;
    }
}
```

And finally I have a `Main` class. Inside the `action` method (in the `Main` class) I want to have an array with these two methods in it in order to select between them if the `type` (shown below) is either `listen` or `text`:

```
public class Main{
    int type = 0;
    public void action(){
        Word word = new Word("Hello");
        // 'Functions' is used to represent something I tried above (just for demonstration)
        Function[] array = {word::incListenCorrect, word::incTextCorrect};
        Function picked = selectOnType(array, word::incTextCorrect);
        picked.call();
    }
    /*
     *  Resources is another class that contains the following values:
     *            public static final int TEXT       = 0;
     *            public static final int LISTEN     = 1;
     */
    private <T> T selectOnType(T[] selection, T defaultOp){
        switch(this.type){
            case Resources.TEXT:
                return selection[Resources.TEXT];
            case Resources.LISTEN:
                return selection[Resources.LISTEN];
            default:
                return defaultOp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are `method1` and `method2` instance methods or static methods?

Comment: your methods are not equivalent to `Function<Void, Void>`, but to  `Runnable`

Comment: @ajb Take a look at the example I included; they are instance methods.

Comment: Use list of `Runnable` like `List<Runnable> array = Arrays.asList(word::incListenCorrect, word::incTextCorrect);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `Function` is a method that takes one argument and returns a result.  You're using methods that take no arguments and do not return results.  You can't use `Function` for this (using `Void` isn't a way to get around this), but [the `java.util.function`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) package contains a number of classes for different common combinations (methods that take no arguments but return a result, methods that take one or two arguments and don't return a result, methods that take primitive arguments or return primitive results that won't work in a `Function` because the types aren't class types, etc.).

There isn't a class *in `java.util.function`* for a functional interface with no arguments and no result, but `Runnable` can be used for that.

You need to make sure you use the correct interface.

**Note:** I was assuming `method1` and `method2` are static methods, so that they don't take any arguments, even a hidden "instance" argument that instance methods take.  If they're instance methods, then things have to be done differently.

Now that you've clarified that they're instance methods, things are different--but it depends on how you get the method.  If you say

```
Word::incListenCorrect
```

since you're using the class name, you need to provide the instance as an argument.  Therefore, `Word::incListenCorrect` returns a functional interface for a method that takes one argument, such as `Consumer<Word>`, and you have to pass the `Word` as the argument when you call the method with `.accept()`.  *But*:

```
word::incListenCorrect
```

is very different.  Now, the `word` instance becomes "baked into" the method reference, so it doesn't need to be passed as an argument.  In this case, therefore, you'll still need the interface that takes no arguments and does not return a value, which is `Runnable`.  When you say

```
Runnable r = word::incListenCorrect;    
r.run();
```

where `r` is a `Runnable`, it will automatically use `word` as the instance for the instance method, since `word` became part of `r` when you assigned the method reference to it.

Comment: I'll take a look at this. Also, take a look at the example I added too for further clarification of what I am doing (i.e. they aren't static methods)

Comment: You, my friend, are fantastic! :) 

Quick question for you, if I had an instance method (like the example above) that took "x" number of arguments and return a result, would I use lambdas for that? I guess I couldn't wrap it into a `Runnable` object anymore because the run() method takes no arguments and is a void function, so what would I wrap it into then?

Comment: The problem here is that you need the correct type, whether it's `Runnable`, `Consumer<T>`, `Function<T,U>`, or whatever.  If there are 1 or 2 arguments, you can use one of the interfaces in `java.util.function` (unless some of the arguments are primitive types, and then you may or may not be able to).  If there are >=3 arguments, you'll need to define your own interface type, and then you can use a method reference.  A lambda won't help you get around the need to define your own type.

Comment: So a function like `public int echo(int x) { return x; }` would not be able to be used by `java.util.function` because of the primitive types (as stated by you above), but could I create an interface, like how you said, to be able to handle something like this? Or am I force to wrap primitives in objects?

Comment: Actually, `java.util.function` does have `IntUnaryOperator` that would be able to handle exactly that kind of function.  You just have to look at the classes listed there and figure out whether it's supported.  If it weren't supported, then yes, you could create your own interface.

Comment: I'd argue that it's not entirely correct to talk about "assigning" method references to instances(the last sentence of the answer). We actually assign instances to method references, not vice versa. I'd rather say that we "take" a method reference from an instance. Latter gives more intuitive understanding of what happens, I feel.

Comment: @MikhailProkhorov I think I was talking about assigning a method reference to a _variable_ (that is, `r`).  I can see how my wording was a bit ambiguous.