# Generic list of actions/funcs

Tags: c#, generics, scheduler

I'm wondering if its possible to create some kind of generic list of actions/funcs, each with different in/out params.

The reason I need this is I have an executer who's job is getting data from an API, each of the methods in that executer goes to a different path in that API, and I want to be able to schedule those requests so I won't overload that API (they will just block me if I pass their threshold of requests).

So each time a method in that executer is called, I will add that method and its params to a list, and another thread will run over the list and execute methods from there using some timeout.

I have to have this logic in the executer and not from it's caller.

So basically wondering if I can do something like:

```
List<Func<T,T>> scheduler;
```

Without declaring the types on creation but instead add different types during runtime.

If there is a better solution or pattern for this please do enlighten me.

[edit]
obviously I don't want to implement something like:

```
Func<List<object>, object> scheduler
```

Comment: Does that question help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813261/how-to-store-delegates-in-a-list

Comment: Where would the parameter values come from? If they are available when you want to schedule the function, simply do a `List<Action>`.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a `List<Tuple<Type, Delegate>>` to store your functions.

The below code runs fine:

```
var scheduler = new List<Tuple<Type, Delegate>>();

scheduler.Add(
    Tuple.Create<Type, Delegate>(
        typeof(Func<int, int>),
        (Func<int, int>)(n => n + 1)));

scheduler.Add(
    Tuple.Create<Type, Delegate>(
        typeof(Func<string, string, int>),
        (Func<string, string, int>)((x, y) => x.Length + y.Length)));
```

You would then need to use reflection to bring them back from being a `Delegate`.

This would be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the parameter values at the time of adding the func to the list, you can simply capture them in a lambda that applies the `Func<T, X, Y, Z ...>` and thus reduce it to a `Func<T>,` e.g.

```
Func<T, X> funcToAdd = ...
Func<T> wrapper = () => funcToAdd(valueForX);
myFuncList.Add(wrapper);
```

The type of the func list can then just be `List<Func<T>>`

Comment: How is the declaration of the list looks like? I can't keep it List<Func<T>>, I have to specify a type

Comment: What are you trying to do with the return values? If the funcs can return anything you can't do any better than `Func<object>` AFAICT